# I want to make an application to book a movie ticket. with master model-1) Screen,2)Movie. then other models 1)movie_screen_mapp,2)Time(with 4 show).

Tags: django

I have to select a movie so that when i select a screen, a movie will display in dropdown which are saved in movie-screen mapping table related to that screen

Comment: Great, good luck with it

Answer (score 0):

check out [github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

you can use `ChainedForeignKey` for this requirement

```
screen = models.ForeignKey('movies.Screen')
movie = ChainedForeignKey('movies.Movie',
                          chained_field='screen',
                          chained_model_field='showing_at',
                          )
```